# Windows system cannot create file with long path

Tags: windows, filesystems

I am installing a package with docker and apparently the file structure of this package contains large paths.

The installation fails with this file:

```
"C:\S\src\vendor\shopware\administration\Resources\app\administration\src\module\sw-cms\elements\product-listing\config\components\sw-cms-el-config-product-listing-config-filter-properties-grid\sw-cms-el-config-product-listing-config-filter-properties-grid.html.twig"
```

and the error that Windows cant find the path specified.

The path is 265 characters long and Windows cannot create it unfortunately.
I already set "LongPathsEnabled" to True in my Registry and rebooted, however the error still appears.

Do you guys know a solution to this?

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by running the docker file in a WSL terminal